# Using only HTML and CSS, how can I used the "checked" status of a radio button to show/hide conditional form fields?

Tags: html, css, forms, conditional-statements, radio-button

I have this working for a checkbox. When I select the checkbox, my two radio buttons appear. But now, if I select one of the radio buttons, I want a block of address fields to appear. I'm not sure why the same thing that is working for the checkbox isn't working for the radio button.

```
<form>
  <input class="no22XAddressRadioButtons_activator" type="checkbox">
  Check if you do not have a physical address within the Oakland Beat 22X boundary.

  <div class="no22XAddressRadioButtons">

    <input class="outsideAddress_activator" type="radio" name="no22XAddress" id="outsideAddress_activator">
    <label for="outsideAddress_activator">My physical address is outside of the 22X boundary.</label><br>

    <input class="noAddress" type="radio" name="no22XAddress" id="no22XAddress">
    <label for="no22XAddress">I don't have a physical address.</label><br>

  </div>

  <!--Begin conditional address-->

  <div class="outsideAddressTextFields">

    Enter your physical address including city, state, and zip code.

    <input class="outsideAddress" type="text">

    <label class="labelText" for="outsideAddress">Number and Street</label>
    <input type="text" name="outsideAddress" id="outsideAddress" required>

  </div>

</form>
```

```
/* Begin conditional radio buttons */

.no22XAddressRadioButtons {
  display: none;
}
.no22XAddressRadioButtons_activator {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.no22XAddressRadioButtons_activator:checked + .no22XAddressRadioButtons {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 45px;
}


/* Begin conditional address */

.outsideAddressTextFields{
  display: none;
}
.outsideAddress_activator:checked + .outsideAddressTextFields {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you're using `+`, an [Adjacent sibling combinator](http://Adjacent%20sibling%20combinator). Which means the block that you need to be made visible, while an input is checked has to be right after the said input. You can use a [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) which I think might be helpful in you case. I've attached a modified code snippet to demonstrate.

As a side note: use [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) to associate an input to a caption.

> You can click the associated label to focus/activate the input, as well as the input itself. This increased hit area provides an advantage to anyone trying to activate the input, including those using a touch-screen device.

```css
/* Begin conditional radio buttons */

.no22XAddressRadioButtons {
  display: none;
}
.no22XAddressRadioButtons_activator {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.no22XAddressRadioButtons_activator:checked ~ .no22XAddressRadioButtons {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 45px;
}


/* Begin conditional address */

.outsideAddressTextFields{
  display: none;
}
.outsideAddress_activator:checked ~ .outsideAddressTextFields {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input id="addressCheck" class="no22XAddressRadioButtons_activator" type="checkbox">
   <label for="addressCheck">Check if you do not have a physical address within the Oakland Beat 22X boundary.</label>

   <div class="no22XAddressRadioButtons">

      <div>
         <input class="outsideAddress_activator" type="radio" name="no22XAddress" id="outsideAddress_activator">
         <label for="outsideAddress_activator">My physical address is outside of the 22X boundary.</label>
         <!--Begin conditional address-->

         <div class="outsideAddressTextFields">
            <div>
               <label for="insideAddress">Enter your physical address including city, state, and zip code.</label>
               <input class="outsideAddress" type="text" id="insideAddress">
            </div>

            <div>
               <label class="labelText" for="outsideAddress">Number and Street</label>
               <input type="text" name="outsideAddress" id="outsideAddress" required>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div>
         <input class="noAddress" type="radio" name="no22XAddress" id="no22XAddress">
         <label for="no22XAddress">I don't have a physical address.</label><br>
      </div>
   </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I see that your example is working when I click "Run code snippet.: I tried just replacing the + with the ~ in my css file, but it didn't change the behavior to the behavior I see from your complete snippet. Is there anything else that is different in your snippet? (Maybe there is an easy way to compare the code. Please forgive me. Super novice.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I carefully compared your code to mine and made all the changes, and it still wasn't working in Chrome. So I created new html and css files with just your code and tried those, and it wasn't working in Chrome. I tried in IE, and it wasn't working there, either. Do you think it is a browser incompatibility or something else? Checkbox works; radio button doesn't.

Comment: I have also modified the HTML markup from your example. What I did was wrap the inputs and their respective blocks in divs. I don't believe browsers will cause issues. here's a Pen with the same code https://codepen.io/rod911/pen/QWbYRJp

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll keep at it at and let you know when I get it working. Really appreciate your help.